# how to use if in this list comprehension

Tags: python

For an array of numbers, I must use list comprehension to find elements that:

1. Are divisible by `6`
2. Their position is also divisible by `6`

For example if the input is:

```
6 12 8 9 1 18
```

The output should be:

```
18
```

Here's what I have already done.

```
print(list(map(int, input().split()))[5::6])
```

I don't know how to find numbers that are divisible by `6`.

Comment: Do you mean position? Cause index 5 is not divisible by 6

Comment: i dont think the index of 18 is divisible by 6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, this code is for you:

```
lst = [6, 12, 8, 9, 1, 18]
[n for i,n in enumerate(lst,1) if not n%6 if not i%6]
# output: [18]
```

or, if you use `input()`:

```
[n for i,n in enumerate(map(int, input().split()), 1) if not n%6 if not i%6]
```

Answer (score 5):

That's how you can do it:

```
[el for idx, el in enumerate(lst) if idx % 6 == 0 and el % 6 == 0]
```

Note that typically indexes start from `0` and so the correct answer is `6`, not `18`. If you want to index from `1` then tweak the above:

```
[el for idx, el in enumerate(lst, 1) if idx % 6 == 0 and el % 6 == 0]
```

Comment: `[n for n in lst[::6] if not n % 6]`

Comment: Why iterate over the whole list when you can slice it to the appropriate indexes first instead? Seems inefficient to me

Comment: @Chris_Rands that sort of microoptimization is completely not worth. And it makes the code less readable.

Comment: I think for large lists and large divisible values, the performance gain may be substantial since slicing is O(k) where k is the slice length, while iterating is O(n) (i agree it's slightly less readable though)

Answer (score 1):

You could use `%` (mod) to get number which can be divided by 6. In short:

```
# my_list is your input list
[x for x in my_list[5::6] if x % 6 == 0]
```

Answer (score 1):

Index of 18 will be 5 because list index starts from 0.
Try  this code :

```
lst = [6,12,8,9,1,18,24]
print(" ".join([str(num) for num in lst if num %6 ==0 and lst.index(num)%6 == 0]))
```

It will return 6 and 24.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the following:

Let's assume that your original list is `original_list`

```
new_list = [original_list[i] for i in range(len(original_list)) if i % 6 == 0 and original_list[I] % 6 == 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

`l = [6, 10, 8, 9, 1, 18, 12]`

`x = [l[i] for i in range(len(l)) if l[i] % 6 == 0 and i % 6 == 0]`

`print(x)`

> op: 6 and 12

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
lst = [6,12,8,9,1,18]
answer = [num for num in lst if num %6 ==0 and lst.index(num)%6 == 0]

Output: 6
```

Note: The answer is not 18 because the index of 18 is 5 as indexing is zero based in python. Therefore only the first number meets both criteria